# On moving a table in JointJs graph, links are not moving with it..They are getting disconnected and only table is moving. How can I correct it?

Tags: javascript, graph, diagram, jointjs

In Joint Js graph , links are getting disconnected on moving the tables ? What might be the issue ? How can I correct it. I have shared the link.Please go through it. You will understand what I am saying.
https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/database

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design. The demo uses a [custom Anchor](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.5/joint.html#anchors.custom) to change the point of the anchor depending on the position.

If you want to change this behavior you can edit the custom router or make your own.

If you want to remove this behavior, you can remove the `defaultAnchor` and `anchorNamespace` options from the JointJS paper. That means it will use the JointJS defaults instead of the custom Anchor.

Although removing these options could make the functionality less desirable in this demo.